# Vectorize not working at all when I run program. What could my issues be?

Tags: python, vectorization, indentation

```
class Document: 
def __init__(self, doc_id):
    # create a new document with its ID
    self.id = doc_id
    # create an empty dictionary 
    # that will hold the term frequency (TF) counts
    self.tfs = {}

def tokenization(self, text):
    # split a title into words, 
    # using space " " as delimiter
    words = text.lower().split(" ")
    for word in words: 
        # for each word in the list
        if word in self.tfs: 
            # if it has been counted in the TF dictionary
            # add 1 to the count
            self.tfs[word] = self.tfs[word] + 1
        else:
            # if it has not been counted, 
            # initialize its TF with 1
            self.tfs[word] = 1


def save_dictionary(diction_data, file_path_name):
    f = open(file_path_name, "w+")

for key in diction_data:
    # Separate the key from the frequency with a space and
    # add a newline to the end of each key value pair
    f.write(key + " " + str(diction_data[key]) + "\n")

f.close()

def vectorize(self, data_path):
Documents = []
for i in range(1, 21):
    file_name = "./textfiles/"+ str(i) + ".txt"
    # create a new document with an ID
doc = Document(i+1)
    #Read the files
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    # compute the term frequencies
    #read in the files contents
doc.tokenization(text)
    # add the documents to the lists
Documents.append(doc)

save_dictionary(doc.tfs, "tf_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")

DFS = {}
for doc in Documents:
    for word in doc.tfs:
        DFS[word] = DFS.get(word,0) + 1

    save_dictionary(doc.DFS, "DFS_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")


vectorize("./")
```

I added the code that I am working with above. I don't get anything when I run it. Is my code wrong or is the code correct with an INDENTATION problem. I am very new to python and coding in general so I am expecting that an indentation issue is one of the problems but want to make sure the code that I am using is correct. If you spot any issues please point them out to me and I'll make the change to fix them.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem is because the indentation of the code example has been completely mangled

Comment: @CJR Is there a better way to copy over to Stack? Everytime I copy it over it gets all messed up. I tried to fix it is that any better?

Comment: Copy the code and paste it in the question as text then - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @wwii Thanks just did it hope it helped

Comment: If the code in your question looks like the code in your editor then you have indentation problems. [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) ..

Comment: @wwii Okay thanks for that. I thought it could be indentation issue since I am very new to this and the indentation part is confusing for me. I will try to take a look and fix it all.

Comment: I fixed the indentation on my end and get TypeError: vectorize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data_path' do you know what that issue may be? @wwii

Comment: The code in your question still has indentation issues - we really cannot tell whether it is because you failed to format your post correctly or if your actual code has indentation problems. Maybe start over, delete this question - fix all your indentation problems in your editor, ask a new question with a [mre] ensuring that the code included in that question is formatted correctly. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: `TypeError: vectorize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data_path'` - `vectorize` looks like it is supposed to be an instance method, that error would be a symptom if you are not calling it *from* an instance. Did you write that code?